# How does Stack Overflow suggest related tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, related-tags

I am in the process of creating a forum where user will be creating tags similar to the way Stack Overflow does.

To allow users to discover more and more questions, I liked the related tags in the right which comes when we visit a page of some particular tag.

So, I wanna know how two tags are considered related ? How can I calculate the distance between tags !

I just need the views or algorithm that can be used to calculate the distance.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "related tags" is nothing special. It just count the posts that have the same sets of tags. Two questions tagged [c] and [d] will show in the "related tags" of tag [c] or [d] as:

in [c]:

> Related tags:
>
> [d](/questions/tagged/d) x 2

in [d]:

> Related tags:
>
> [c](/questions/tagged/c) x 2

Comment: ohh Great :) I didn't know it was that easy !! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How to do it efficiently when we have to find out related tags for a set of tags ?

Comment: @PrashantSingh use `OR` or `AND` between the tags